# R using Java Gives Wrong p-value for Iris Dataset

Tags: r

The Java code below reads the included R "iris" dataset, yet, although the Chi-Sq and df match, the p-value is *different* using Java.

In R, I'm reading the Iris table the same was as in Java, like this:

```
mydata <- read.table('iris.csv', sep=',', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactor=FALSE)
```

Running this dataset in R, the p-value is 2.2e-16, yet using the same dataset from the Java side gives me a p-value of 3.352034178317223E-20.

No idea why the p-values aren't the same given that the two other statistics are the same.

Would appreciate suggestions what might be wrong with the Java code approach below.

Thanks.

---

```java
rConnection.eval("library('biotools')");

String tableRead = "read.table('iris.csv', sep=',', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactor=FALSE)";

REXP boxMResult =  rConnection.eval("boxM("+ tableRead+ "[,-5],"  + tableRead + "[, 5])");
```

Comment: these don't see all that different. I'm not familiar with Java, but I would guess this is a difference in how really small numbers are represented.

Comment: The value from R says it's "less than" the e-16. so, the number received from Java IS smaller than that. I was just wondering. Thanks for your reply.